# Arithmetic on a pointer to void (looks like easy to solve but i did not understand how to do this)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am unable to find the how to do this 
I am getting the following error as shown in image

[image]
I searches a lot but i did not understand how to do this

I am facing this error in ASIHttpRequest.m

Please please guide me

Thank u so much in advance

Comment: In the targets i placed the compiler as Objective C++  In targets "According to file type"  because i integrated openCV in my app thats why i palced the compliers like this... If i place the compilers both  are in "According to file type" i am getting "Lexical processor error map file not found error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How recent is your copy of ASIHttpRequest? My version looks different - there is some typecasting around that pointer arithmetic. Also, which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: can u please send me the link from where u downloaded the ASIHttpRequest files? @Echelon

Comment: Thank u i downloaded the files from this link https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/downloads
It is working now .. @Echelon